# C# bot Framework Replace Luis Dialog with other NLP Service

Tags: c#, botframework

I have created my own NLP api service using Apache OpenNlp. It will return json data (sample)
`{"intent": "Feedback",  "entity": {}, "status": true}`
Previously I used LUIS, So Bot framework having inbuilt reference class for processing  LUIS api call and providing us Intent and result. Based on the Intent our method will be like below

```
[LuisIntent("Feeback")]
    public async Task Feedback(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
```

But, If I'm not using LUIS service. What will be the best way or how can we do the Intent process and remaining Bot Process. Something like

```
case "Feeback"    
Public async Task Feedback(IDialogContext Context) {
```

in my existing bot framework project.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the same paradigm.

Here's an example of using Wit.ai instead of LUIS

https://github.com/q3blend/BotBuilder-Wit.ai/

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks @blenddd . Will try.